# Flask with ajax response is not redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

When I send the URL back to my javascript file from the flask view function, no redirecting takes place and instead it returns a `Type error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

My view function:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('check')
        values = request.json
        print(values)
        result = db.session.query(Emp_Details).filter_by(ID=values['ID']).first()
        print(result.Password)
        if result.Password == values['Password'] and result.Department == 'HR':
                print(jsonify(url=url_for('hr_department')))
                return jsonify(url=url_for('hr_department'))
        elif result.Password == values['Password'] and result.Department == 'DEVELOPMENT':
                return url_for('devs')
        else:
            abort(401)
    else:

        return render_template("login.html")
```

My Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                    type :"POST",
                    url :"/login",
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                    data : JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'),
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function (data) {
                        window.location.href = data['url']
                    },
                    error : function (response) {
                        alert(response)

                    },


                });
```

The log in my console:

```
check
{'Password': 'leechan2', 'ID': '10090'}
leechan2
<Response 25 bytes [200 OK]>
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2016 23:34:37] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
check
None
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2016 23:34:37] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/gautham/Intern-flask/Intern/App.py", line 24, in login
    result = db.session.query(Emp_Details).filter_by(ID=values['ID']).first()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2016 23:34:37] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2016 23:34:37] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2016 23:34:37] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2016 23:34:37] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2016 23:34:37] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2016 23:34:37] "GET /login?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: use `print(values)` to see what you have in variable. It seems it is `None`.

Comment: Now I see in your log that `values` is `None` - you can use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox to see what data is send by browser when it runs `$.ajax`

Comment: how looks data which you convert to JSON in `$.ajax` ? If I use `data = {'ID': 'foobar'};` then `JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'),` sends it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have something wrong with `data` which you send:

This works for me if I use

```
data = {'ID': 'foobar'};
```

HTML:

```
<script>

    data = {'ID': 'foobar'};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test/ajax",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = data['url']
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert(response)
        },
    });

</script>
```

Flask:

```
@app.route('/test/ajax', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_ajax():

    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.json
        print('data:', data)

        result = {'url': url_for('index')}
        print('result:', result)

        return jsonify(result)

    else:
        return render_template('test-ajax.html')
```

Comment: As you can see even my variable 'data' has values in it for the first time but I  can't understand why my login page is called even though there is a redirect and you can clearly see in the log only on the second time variable 'data' is empty. Whenever I click login button it calls the login method twice for which first time proper data is sent second time again the login page is called automatically with empty 'data' variable. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to reply to this but, For those who come here and are using Fetch API, the response by @furas never worked for me.

But this solution below worked

The response on the Browser/Client side(Under Developer tools) would look like this

```
 Response{type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/billing/print_receipt/20", redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true}
```

and the Javascript redirection would be done like this

```
if(response.ok & response.redirected){
    location.replace(response.url)
}
```